# useUTC don't work

Tags: javascript, highcharts, utc

I'm trying to have the correct time on my charts but even if I use the useUTC = false in this code :

```
success: function(data) { 
            var options= {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'rendu_graph<?=$instance_graph?>',
                    type: 'spline'
                },
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Graph des relevés des sondes' 
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'

                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %b %Y %H:%M', this.x)+  ' : ' + this.y;
                    }
                },

                series: [] 

            }
```

All option works fine but i still have the time stamp for 00:00 and hight chart show me 22h00. I'm in a GMT+2 (in real +1 but it's summer time so we have a GMT+1 +1 => GMT+2)

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You should [useUTC](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC) like this:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });
```

Comment: Okayyy ! It seems we can't prepare global option before like I do :-/ Thanks very much even I have read this answer many mnay times I never think it was a declaration pb.